# When not to use static keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, class, static

What makes it a poor practice to use static keyword when defining a method in C#?
I know that with `static` we can reach directly to the function in the class without creating an instance of the class. But when we shouldn't use static?

Comment: If the method doesn't need to access any *instance* members, you should define it as `static`. It might still be declared as a `private` method.

Comment: `But when we shouldn't use static?` When you want to be able to mock it for unit testing is one example. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5757/is-static-universally-evil-for-unit-testing-and-if-so-why-does-resharper-recom

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete explanation for the use of the 'static' property [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) by Microsoft.

In a web framework's experience (.NET Core for this) for instance, we use static declaration for primitive values that WILL NOT require any change.

Answer (score 0):

A method that does not access any instance data should actually be marked as `static`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1822-mark-members-as-static?view=vs-2017 It might still be declared as a `private` method depending on the usage.

If the method does access any instance data it *cannot* be static. The compiler enforces this.

Common examples of static methods are for example `String.Format` and `Int32.Parse`. It makes no sense to allocate a `string` or an `int` before calling these methods.

Answer (score 0):

You create a static method when you don' t need the method to access any of the non-static elements on your class. For example take in account `DateTime.Parse` method. You can create an instance of `DateTime` as usual but if you need to parse a specific date, you can call `DateTime.Parse` to return a valid DateTime without creating a `DateTime` instance per se. As that method does not access any specific element of DateTime class, it is declared as `static`

More info:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1208992/When-to-use-static-methods-Csharp

https://hackernoon.com/c-static-vs-instance-classes-and-methods-50fe8987b231